# readline module not functioning in Pycharm

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I am attempting to have a default value in the terminal when asking for input in python3.  This is the function I'm using that I found in a different stackoverflow answer.

```
def rlinput(prompt, prefill=''):
    readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(prefill))
    try:
        return input(prompt)
    finally:
        readline.set_startup_hook()
```

When I tested this in a small program run in the terminal it works fine.  But when run in my larger program in pycharm it doesn't work at all.  It seems as though readline doesn't work in pycharm or something.  Any calls to readline functions don't run.

However when I ran the larger program from the terminal the readline functions worked fine.  So is there something in pycharm that I have to configure to get this to work?  I've already downloaded and installed the readline package in the project interpreter and imported the module so I'm just not sure where the problem stems from.

Comment: Does pycharm have the proper permissions?

Comment: I'm not a Pycharm user, but it's a GUI application, isn't it?  Any input to a program running within it would presumably be coming from a text entry widget of some sort, NOT an actual terminal which is where `readline` works.

Comment: @jasonharper It seems you are correct.  I looked into it and the run console in pycharm is not a terminal.  It can try to emulate it with a setting but it still doesn't do what I need it to do.  So I just get around it by running my program in pycharm's embedded terminal.